# Trying to find my Directory for my Desktop Background for a python program

Tags: python, background, directory, desktop

Does anyone now how to find the Directory for where my desktop Background is stored or is it just stored where ever the actual image Im using for my BG is

this is the code i want the image to be saved and become MY desktop BG im running Windows XP

```
import os
import sys
import time
import Image
import ImageGrab

import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new(input("Gimme URL: "))

SaveDirectory=r'C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Pictures'
ImageEditorPath=r'C:\WINDOWS\system32\mspaint.exe'
img=ImageGrab.grab()
box = (100, 100, 400, 400)
region = img.crop(box)
saveas=os.path.join(SaveDirectory,'ScreenShot_'+time.strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')+'.png')
img.save(saveas)
editorstring='""%s" "%s"'% (ImageEditorPath,saveas) 
os.system(editorstring)
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context?  Setting an image as the background on any system shouldn't mess with the source, so that seems like it will always be a safe bet.

Comment: Well im trying to save a snapshot as my Background when i run the program

Comment: You should edit your question to include that, and any (partially) working code you have.  As well as details like what OS you are running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/435877-change-the-wallpaper-under-windows/) and the comments for it. You can set the desktop background with Python via the Windows API, but there are some caveats.

Comment: Thanks thats what i ended up doing!